# KVM DNS access guest by using its hostname (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: dns, kvm-virtualization, interface, virtualization, resolv.conf

I have a guest machine running ubuntu 14.04 on an Ubuntu 14.04 host running KVM/QEMU.

Everything works fine except for one thing. Given my guest's hostname is `virtual-machine-1`, I would like to be able to find it from the host machine.

In especially, if I use `host virtual-machine-1` on the host machine, I would like it to return the guest's IP address.

The documentation on [KVM/Networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking) states:

> If on your host machine you add 192.168.122.1 (the default IP of your
>   host in libvirt) as your first nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf [... blabla it should work]

And this indeed works. But the `resolv.conf` file is regularly overwritten and the extra added line gets lost.

Which leads me to my question: ***What is the appropriate way to reflect this change?***

Here's what I've tried to no avail:

- adding it to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`
- adding the dns-nameserver to my `/etc/network/interfaces` file

It seems like the nameserver 192.168.122.1 needs to precede any other (including 127.0.1.1). The documentation states that this is normal and that dnsmasq will handle it correctly. I just don't know how to configure this in a lasting manner.

Comment: There's a `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file as well. Did you try adding to that?

Comment: It reads `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN` so I haven't tried.

Comment: If you notice, that's the exact same header that is shown in `/etc/resolv.conf` generated by resolvconf, because it uses that file as the header. Neither base nor head are ever overwritten, but stuff in head always appears before base (there also maybe a `tail`). :)

Comment: @muru Duh I feel a little dumb. This obviously works and I don't think there are any counter indications. If you wish you can answer the question and I'll select it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resolvconf` generates `/etc/resolv.conf` using files from `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d/`, which usually contains a `head`, a `base` and maybe a `tail`. From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/resolvconf.8.html):

```
   The dynamically generated resolver  configuration  file  always  starts
   with  the  contents of /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head and ends with
   the contents of /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail.  Between  head  and
   tail  the  libc  script inserts dynamic nameserver information compiled
   from, first, information provided for  configured  interfaces;  second,
   static  information  from /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base.
```

As you may have observed, the generated `/etc/resolv.conf` has a header warning that the contents are generated and the file should not be edited manually. This header is stored in `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d/head`, so don't be confused by the presence of that warning in `head`. Files in `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d` are not generated, and are meant for manualy editing if needed. So if any entries absolutely have to appear
at the top of `resolv.conf`, add them to `head`. If the entries absolutely have to appear at the end (for example, the last `search` entry is always used), add them in `tail`.

Comment: Note for readers: if you are on a Debian-based distro, you may find that you do not have an `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d/` directory, or that running `man resolvconf` yields `No manual entry for resolvconf`. Chances are, your distro will allow you to easily fix this by running `apt install resolvconf` (or, for the old-fashioned, `apt-get install resolvconf`).